# How to fix a contour color of a 2D cut with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

Please I would like to have unique black lines for my 2D contour.

```
set terminal png size 800,800 font 'Times New Roman, 12'
set output 'TH1.png'
set view map
set pm3d map
unset surface
set cont base
set cntrparam levels 50
set isosamples 10
unset key 
set xrange[0:180]
set yrange[0:180]
set xlabel '{/Symbol q}'
set ylabel '{/Symbol q}''
set palette rgb 33,13,10
splot 'TH1TH2.dat' w ima, 'TH1TH2.dat' w l lt -4 lw 1.6
```

For values great than 2000 I want a red contour.
Can someone help me?
Here is my 2D cut[image] But I would like to have only the black lines.
[link for the data](https://files.fm/u/apsq8ejmb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be ideal if we could use the original data (maybe minimized). Anyway, the following example creates its own data.
If you need further explanations please let me know.

**Script:**

```
### contour lines with custom colors
reset session

set pm3d
set contour 
set cntrparam levels 20

### create some test data
set table $Data
    set isosamples 100
    set samples 100
    f(x,y)=(sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x))*4000/3.+2000
    splot [-5:5][-5:5] f(x,y)
unset table

set palette rgb 33,13,10
set size ratio 1
unset key
set tics out
set view map
set xrange[:] noextend
set yrange[:] noextend

myColor(v) = v>=2000 ? 0xff0000 : 0x000000

plot $Data index 0 u 1:2:3 w image, \
        '' index 1:999 u 1:2:(myColor($3)) w l lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (with OP's data, please reduce for a *minimal* example.)

I'm still confused. Ok, contour lines all in black, but values above 2000 in red? You could use the ternary operator to map all values >=2000 to the fixed value of 6000 (which will be red).

**Script:**

```
### contour lines with custom colors
reset session

FILE = 'TH1TH2.dat'

set pm3d
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels 20

set table $Contour
    splot FILE u 1:2:3
unset table

set palette rgb 33,13,10
set size ratio 1
unset key
set tics out
set xrange[0:180]
set yrange[0:180]

myValue(v) = v>=2000 ? 6000 : v

plot FILE u 1:2:(myValue($3)) w image, \
     $Contour u 1:2 w l lc "black"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Script 2:**

```
### contour lines with custom colors
reset session

FILE = 'TH1TH2.dat'

set pm3d
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels discrete -2000,-1800,-1600,-1400,-1200,-1000,-800,-600,-400-200,0,\
      200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,2000

set table $Contour
    splot FILE u 1:2:3 every 10
unset table

set palette rgb 33,13,10
set size ratio 1
unset key
set tics out
set xrange[0:180]
set yrange[0:180]

myValue(v) = v>=2000 ? 6000 : v

plot FILE u 1:2:(myValue($3)) w image, \
     $Contour u 1:2 w l lc "black"
### end of script
```

**Result 2:**

[image]

Comment: is it possible to plot all the lines with black color?  I have 03 columns

Comment: @Herve yes, use `'' index 1:999 u 1:2 w l lc "black"`. However, what did you mean with "For values great than 2000 I want a red color"?

Comment: I attached the data

Comment: I mean values above 2000 must be in red

Comment: Please see https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/custom_contours.html for a worked example of customizing the color/dash properties of individual contour lines.

Comment: @Ethan thanks for that link. `set cntrparam firstlinetype N`, a feature which exists apparently since gnuplot 5.2.3. However, I don't see right away how to make them all the same line style, e.g. solid, black. I don't want to have to specify 20 or 30 linestyles first. Well, maybe I could do it in a loop.

Comment: @Herve not sure whether this is what you wanted. If this answered your question please check the check mark at the top left of the answer indicating that your problem is solved. Maybe the values above 2000 should be in various shades of red like Ethan suggested with the blue/white/red palette?

Comment: @theozh I can work with the script you provided me. Please which command can I use to do the fit? For example, if I want to increase the grid points.

Comment: @Herve which fit? which grid points? Do you mean the number of points on the contour lines? Maybe `set samples 1000; set isosamples 1000`. Default is 100 and 10.

Comment: @theozh I mean the grid points. Like Making the curves smooth. For example, if I have 2, 5, 6, 9, 12. I can fit to get something like 2, 2.2, 2.2, 3, 3.2, 5, .....

Comment: @Herve I don't understand. Where is a grid? The contour lines are already pretty smooth (at least in the plot above). What is 2,5,6,9,12? x,y,z, or contour level or something else? And what is 2, 2.2, 2.2, 3, 3.2, ...   (twice 2.2 ?)

Comment: @theozh I am asking you because I will do a fitting. How to increase the number of x, y, z points?

Comment: @Herve increase the number of your x,y,z input datapoints? Maybe by linear interpolation? What should this help for fitting? What are you fitting? This seems to me a completely different question, not related to the contour line question above.

Comment: @theozh  yes! I mean interpolation.

Comment: @Herve I guess not out-of-the-box. Check `help dgrid3d` for ungridded data, but I think you can only plot it but write to a table. If you want a table, I guess you would have to use external tools or write some extra gnuplot script. Please open a new question since this is a different topic.

Comment: @theozh Please I have some issues with my figure. There are some missed points. In principle here is what I want to do in my figure. 
- make sure that for energies above 2000  the color is the same: red
- Make sure that I have contours by 100 or 200 between -2000  and 1000  for example.

Comment: @Herve Phew, it seems to be a riddle in guessing what you actually want. Can't you give a clear and complete specification right away in your question? Now, the colorbar together with the graph looks a bit strange because there are no values and colors for 2000 to 6000 anymore in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Your original figure attached to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74431503/2d-cut-using-gnuplot) was a good figure.  It showed the zero-level using a single black contour line, and showed regions of higher/lower values using palette coloring.  In my judgment adding more lines in various colors is not an improvement; it adds clutter and confusion without conveying any new information.  You would do better to stick with the original figure.

It would be possible, however, to add more emphasis to which areas are negative and which are positive.  You could do this by defining a palette with a neutral color at 0 and two different color gradients indicating negative or positive values.  For example:

```
set palette defined (-1 "orange-red", 0 "white", 1 "dark-blue")
test palette
```

[image]

Compared to the original palette, this makes it harder to judge precise values at any given point but makes it easier to focus on the positive or negative peaks.